# Powershell GUI 'save file dialog' version of Get-FilePath?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, savefiledialog

I have a working GUI and a script for editing large text files;
I started out with two text boxes to manually add the input path and output path. To make this faster I'd like to add Buttons to open a browser window for open/save file.

So far I have

```
$button1.Add_Click({$textinput.text = Get-Filepath})
```

That gives me my input file and displays it's full path. Is there a command for a save file dialog or do I need something totally different?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$button1.Add_Click({
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog'
    if ($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK')
    {
        $textinput.text = $OpenFileDialog.FileName
    }
})
```